# GitLab CI Pipeline: MySQL Service Fails with "missing signature key" Error When Pulling Image

Tags: laravel, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been running a GitLab CI pipeline with a MySQL service for a while now without any issues. Recently, the MySQL service suddenly stopped working, and I started getting the following error when the pipeline tries to start it:

`WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": missing signature key (manager.go:237:1s) ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "mysql:8.0.34" with specified policies [always]: missing signature key (manager.go:237:1s)`

Here's the relevant portion of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
dusk:
    stage: test
    image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:php-8.2
    allow_failure: true
    dependencies:
        - composer
        - npm
    variables:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
        DB_HOST: mysql
        DB_CONNECTION: mysql
        DB_USERNAME: root
        DB_PASSWORD: root
    services:
        - mysql:8.0.34
    script:
        - cp .env.dusk.cicd .env
        - configure-laravel
        - start-nginx-ci-project
        - php artisan dusk:chrome-driver
        - php artisan dusk --filter=CompanyTest
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - tests/Browser/screenshots
```

Furthermore, this is the config.toml for the GitLab runner:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  url = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  id = 1
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-07-18T13:32:38Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.7"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 2073741824
    allowed_pull_policies = ["always", "if-not-present", "never"]
```

`docker info` output:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.21.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 2
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 24.0.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 61f9fd88f79f081d64d6fa3bb1a0dc71ec870523
 runc version: v1.1.9-0-gccaecfc
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 16
 Total Memory: 15.49GiB
 Name: xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx
 ID: 841f142c-375f-4e6c-98d7-2f19e2a21b7a
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I'm a bit lost at this point, and I'm not sure what might be causing this. Any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this error would be greatly appreciated!

Things I've tried:

1. I removed the MySQL image from the gitlab-runner cache thinking it might be a corrupted image, but that didn't help.
2. Checked the GitLab runner configurations and Docker settings for any discrepancies.
3. Reviewed recent changes to .gitlab-ci.yml to see if there's anything that might have triggered this, but the configurations related to MySQL seem unchanged.

### Edit 1:

For now I've managed to change the repository from https://registery.gitlab.com to https://registery1.docker.io. This seems to be a working workaround although it does not solve the original issue.

Comment: What version of `docker` are you using on your runner? Can you show the output of `docker info` on your runner?

Comment: On the runner we're using version `24.0.6`. I'll add the `docker info` output to the original post. For now I've managed to change the repository from `https://registery.gitlab.com` to `https://registery1.docker.io`. This seems to be a working workaround although it does not solve the original issue.